I get a "Web Socket Error" when using the API in customtkinter's GUI. How do I keep the connection open?
I would like to embed the vtubestudio and voicevox APIs into a GUI button created with customtkinter (henceforth abbreviated as ctk) and create a program that runs vtubestudio and voicevox when the button is pressed. However, when I prototype and run the program, I get a "web socket error". This probably indicates that the server side of the API is not up to the task.
Here is the program
from voicevox_adapter import VoicevoxAdapter
from play_sound import PlaySound
import pyvts
import asyncio
import customtkinter as ctk

input_str = "こんにちは"
va = VoicevoxAdapter()
ps = PlaySound("スピーカー")
data,rate = va.get_voice(input_str)
app = ctk.CTk()
app.geometry("400x240")

plugin_info = {
    "plugin_name": "trigger hotkey",
    "developer": "OverHome",
    "authentication_token_path": "./pyvts_token.txt"
}

async def voice():
    ps.play_sound(data,rate)

async def main():
    myvts = pyvts.vts(plugin_info=plugin_info)
    await myvts.connect()
    await myvts.request_authenticate_token()  # get token
    await myvts.request_authenticate()  # use token
    response_data = await myvts.request(myvts.vts_request.requestHotKeyList())
    hotkey_list = []
    for hotkey in response_data['data']['availableHotkeys']:
        hotkey_list.append(hotkey['name'])
    send_hotkey_request = myvts.vts_request.requestTriggerHotKey(hotkey_list[0])  
    return myvts,send_hotkey_request

myvts, send_hotkey_list = asyncio.run(main())

async def doing():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await myvts.request(send_hotkey_list)
    await voice()

def doing_def():
    asyncio.run(doing())

button = ctk.CTkButton(app,
                       text="実行",
                       command=doing_def,
                       width=200,height=120)
button.grid(column=2,row=1)

app.mainloop()

From the error message, I believe the problem is occurring in the myvts.request(send_hotkey_list) section. I believe this is because the WebSocket connection is already closed and the vts connection is disconnected at the end of the main() run. How can I make sure the connection is always open?
Here is the full error
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 963, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1033, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1108, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 1165, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\framing.py", line 68, in read
    data = await reader(2)
  File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 723, in readexactly
    await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
  File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 517, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "c:\Users\HOME　anyone\Documents\AIVtuberProject\voicevox\async&ctk.py", line 42, in doing_def
    asyncio.run(doing())
  File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\HOME　anyone\Documents\AIVtuberProject\voicevox\async&ctk.py", line 38, in doing
    await myvts.request(send_hotkey_list)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyvts\vts.py", line 112, in request
    await self.websocket.send(json.dumps(request_msg))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 635, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 939, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent


if problem makes server then you may only catch exception in try/except and inform user that there was problem with server -e.g use MessageBox.

other idea - you have async function async def voice(): but it doesn't run any await function - and sometime this can make problem. It may need to remove async from async def voice(): and run it as voice() without await

error shows problem with await myvts.request(send_hotkey_list) but I wonder if you shouldn't run await myvts.connect() and ...authenticat... in this function because it could already close connection.
